# Designing classes and interfaces with generic types

Tags: generics, interface, kotlin

I have the following interface that maps and accepts as a parameter a `InsectTypesEntity` and return a object of a `InsectDataModel` and another that returns a `List<InsectDataModel>`

I am trying to do this with generics, as I would like to practice this.

```
interface InsectInteractorMapper<T> {
    fun map(insectTypesEntity: T): T
    fun map(cursor: Cursor): List<T>
}
```

Without the generics it would be something like this:

```
interface InsectInteractorMapper<InsectTypesEntity> {
    fun map(insectTypesEntity: InsectTypesEntity): InsectDataModel
    fun map(cursor: Cursor): List<InsectDataModel>
}
```

I am trying to get my class that implements this using the generic version of the interface, however, I get many errors related:

```
1) Return type is 'insectDataModel' which is not a subtype of overridden
public abstract fun map(insectTypesEntity: InsectTypesEntity): InsectTypeEntity defined in InsectInteractorMapper

2) Return type is 'List<InsectDataModel>' which is not a subtype of overridden
public abstract fun map(cursor: Cursor): List<InsectTypesEntity> defined in InsectInteractorMapper
```

The class that implements the interface

```
class InsectInteractorMapperImp: InsectInteractorMapper<InsectTypesEntity> {
    override fun map(insectTypesEntity: InsectTypesEntity): InsectDataModel {

        return InsectDataModel(
                insectTypesEntity.friendlyName,
                insectTypesEntity.scientificName,
                insectTypesEntity.classification,
                insectTypesEntity.imageAsset,
                insectTypesEntity.dangerLevel)
    }

    override fun map(cursor: Cursor): List<InsectDataModel> {
        val insectDataModelList: MutableList<InsectDataModel> = mutableListOf()

        cursor.moveToFirst()
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            InsectDataModel().let {
                it.friendlyName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(InsectContract.COLUMN_FRIENDLY_NAME))
                it.scientificName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(InsectContract.COLUMN_SCIENTIFIC_NAME))
                it.dangerLevel = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(InsectContract.COLUMN_DANGER_LEVEL))

                insectDataModelList.add(it)
            }
        }

        cursor.close()
        return insectDataModelList.toList()
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to get this working correctly with generics?

many thanks for any suggestions,

==== UPDATE
Modified interface for in/out variance:

```
interface InsectInteractorMapper<in E, out M> {
    fun map(insectTypesEntity: E): M
    fun map(cursor: Cursor): List<M>
}
```

However, I am getting a warning when I try and use the interface:

```
unchecked assignment java.util.List to java.util.List<InsectDataModel> Reason insectDataModelMapper has raw type so result of map will be erased
```

When I use it like this:

```
insectInteractorMapper = new InsectInteractorMapperImp();
insectDataModelList = insectInteractorMapper.map(cursor);
```

Comment: How does your declaration of `InsectInteractorMapperImp` look like after the update?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you want a `in` type and an `out` type you need to declare those like so:

```
interface InsectInteractorMapper<in T1, out T2> {
    fun map(insectTypesEntity: T1): T2
    fun map(cursor: Cursor): List<T2>
}
```

Then your code will work

Comment: that answer did work, thanks. However, I am getting a unchecked warning with the assignment. I have updated my question

Comment: @ant2009 what type if list is `insectDataModelList ` ? is it a list of `InsectDataModel`?

Comment: derek, yes it is a InsectDataModel. This is the declaration `private List<InsectDataModel> insectDataModelList = Collections.emptyList();` It is in a java class.

Comment: @ant2009 What if you put `List<InsectDataModel> insectDataModelList = insectInteractorMapper.map(cursor);` do you get the same warning? The warning pretty much says the list you have doesn't match the list it will return

Comment: @ant2009 you can also ignore it by adding `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` above the function if you know the type